# Why isn't my custom delegate working?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to build a delegate to allow me to pass data form a child view controller to the parent. I've been looking at various tutorials / questions online but my delegate method isn't being triggered.

Could you take a look at my code below and see if I'm missing anything?

TownListViewController.h

```
@protocol TownListViewControllerDelegate;

@interface TownListViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {

    id <TownListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <TownListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol TownListViewControllerDelegate
@optional

- (void)didSelectTown:(Town *)town;

@end
```

TownListViewController.m

```
@implementation TownListViewController

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [delegate didSelectTown:(Town *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

SearchViewController.h

```
@interface SearchViewController : UITableViewController <TownListViewControllerDelegate> {

...

}
```

SearchViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TownListViewController * townViewController = [[TownListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TownListViewController" bundle:nil];
    townViewController.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:townViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)didSelectTown:(Town *)town
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectTown fired");
    self.selectedTown = town;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your delegate implementation is correct. I'd always check if the delegate respondsToSelector though as you are declaring the delegate method as optional so if your object does not implement you will get a crash. Your problem could be in the didSelectRowAtIndexpath - is it definitely getting called?

Comment: Spot on! The method I thought was pushing the TownListViewController to the stack (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) wasn't being called instead it was being pushed by another method which wasn't setting the delegate. On another note, I'm trying to add the respondsToSelector, but it comes up saying "-respondsToSelector not found", any ideas?

Comment: `if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectTown:)]) { [self.delegate didSelectTown:town];}`

Comment: make delegate conforms to protocol NSObject. i.e. id <NSObject, TownListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

Answer (score 0):

try to reloadData after set the delegate. I think the first call to reloadData of table occurs during the initWithNibName of the TownListViewController... Anyway can you post the `delegate` value on this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I bet is nil...

By the way is a good practice to check if the variable `delegate` conforms the protocol, try adding this line under supposing that the method is optional:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([delegate conformsToProtocol(TownListViewControllerDelegate)] && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectTown:objectAtIndexPath:)])
        [delegate didSelectTown:(Town *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The solution in the end was that the didSelectRowAtIndexPath that set the delegate wasn't being called when I was expecting. With regards to your good practice tip, I'm trying to add the respondsToSelector, but it comes up saying "-respondsToSelector not found", any ideas?